# Splitting Inputs and storing in different variables c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, arrays, split

Below is my old code that works well if the input is like this "01/01/2017"

```
string monthfrom;
                    string yearfrom;
                    string valfrom = "01/01/2017";
                    valfrom = valfrom.Replace("/", string.Empty);
                    monthfrom = valfrom.Substring(0, 2);
                    yearfrom = valfrom.Substring(valfrom.Length - 4);
                    pdfFormFields.SetField("Month[0]", monthfrom);
                    pdfFormFields.SetField("Year[0]", yearfrom);
```

> Results: Month[0] = 01 Year[0] = 2017

but if the input is like this 1/1/2017 the results will be like this

> Month[0] = 11 Year[0] = 2017

I know that the cause of the error is because of this monthfrom = valfrom.Substring(0, 2); , So I changed the code to be like this.

```
char[] delimiterChars = { '/' };
                    string text = "1/1/2017";
                    string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);
                    string result = string.Empty;
                    foreach (string s in words)
                    {
                        result += s;
                    }//foreach
```

But I have a problem here , I want the inputs to be in different variables but I dont know how to do it nor have a single idea.

Below is my out put goal if the inputs are 1/1/2017 & 01/01/2017

Input:1/1/2017

> Month = 1 Day = 1 Year = 2017

Input: 01/01/2017

> Month = 01 , Day = 01, Year = 2017

Comment: why not changing value from 1/1/2017 to dateValue.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"); first to get 01/01/2017? this is a solution for your first code

Comment: You should not be doing this kind of stuff manually instead use the methods provided on the DateTime class for parsing.

Comment: oh, if it is not a datetime and its value is just a string input, converting string is not an option. I just gave it incase  it came from DateTime

Comment: as @loneshark99 said, it would be best to use a class such as DateTime to make things easier. However, if you're just doing this for fun or your own learning, you basically have everything as separate variables where you wrote `string[] words = text.Split(delimiterChars);`. All you have to do is reference each one by index. For example, day will be stored in `words[1]`

Comment: The wording of the Question, naming convention, and Desired Results a;; are saying that you are parsing Dates... Which is inconsistent with the comment of it not being a `DateTime`, and it could just be a string. I almost though that maybe you were going with someone entering in _January 1, 2017`  but that would totally screw up your `substringi`ng and prevent the `split() `. So maybe you want to give up some more sample test scenarios and desired results; error entries included.

Answer (score 1):

```
string x = "1/1/2017";
string y = "01/01/2017";
DateTime dateTime;
if (DateTime.TryParse(y, out dateTime))
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Day = {dateTime.Day}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Month = {dateTime.Month}");
    Console.WriteLine($"Year = {dateTime.Year}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Date cannot be parsed");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Parse the date time and then get the relevant fields. In that case you do not need to worry about format of string.

```
 public class ParsedDate
        {
            public int day   { get; set; }
            public int month { get; set; }
            public int year  { get; set; }
        }


        public ParsedDate ParseDate(string inputString)
        {
            DateTime outDate;

            ParsedDate returnObject = new ParsedDate();

            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(inputString))
            {
                throw new ArgumentException("String can not be empty");
            }

            DateTime.TryParse(inputString, out outDate);

            if (outDate != null)
            {
                returnObject = new ParsedDate
                {
                    day = outDate.Day,
                    month = outDate.Month,
                    year = outDate.Year
                };
            }

            return returnObject;
        }
```